# Как правильно использовать delete()?

Tags: java, android

Добрый день, написал метод для удаления файлов, после его вызова файлы удаляются не сразу, а только после их обновления и открытия одного из них для просмотра в чём может быть причина ?

```
 private void delFile() {

            File folder = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Photo_and_Video");
            File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
            for(File f : listOfFiles ) {
                f.delete(); //удаление файлов из списка поочередно.
            }
```

Comment: Расставьте знаки препинания, а то непонятно какую причину вы хотите выяснить

Comment: @АндроидАндроид немного перефразировал

Comment: Вероятно причина в файловом браузере, который не обновляет список файлов после удаления.

Comment: @woesss а можно по подробней ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если `f.delete() == true` то вы все делаете правильно. Повторно "открывать" фалы не нужно (что бы это не значило).

Скорее всего вы неправильно проверяет удалился ли файл.

Comment: Куда уж правильней, после вызова метода delFile() открываю папку смотрю все на месте и даже превью у каждого, далее обновляю папку исчезает превью, но файлы остаются открываю один из них изображения нет далее закрываю файл и секунды через 2 они исчезают. И пока этих действий не сделаешь они никуда не денутся.

Comment: Видимо вы проверяете каким-то файловым менеджером. А они обычно кешируют данные.

проверяйте так : File.exist()